# How can I create a default dock for all users (Mavericks)?

Tags: macos, dock

I am new to managing Macs. We currently have a lab, and probably plan to create more labs in an enterprise style solution. In the lab, we would like to have a "default profile" created for users who log in.

The users are AD users, and the Macs are bound (binded?) to AD; users can log in fine.

I would now like to modify the dock to display specific installed applications. **I then want this dock to be the default dock for any users that log in.**

Ideally, I would also like to use this default dock on other machines in the lab, so if there are some files I can transfer to the other machines and a command to run to apply the settings, that would be perfect. Ideally I will be Apple or Bash scripting the entire process (currently Bash scripting the AD bind, default background, apple ID sign-in removal, etc).

We have no management servers. We will be using Deep Freeze for the time being, so there is no problem with users modifying their dock; users will have permissions to mess around.

I have found answers for pre-Mavericks, where it seems to be a case of copying a couple of files which would have been perfect, but it seems Mavericks does it a little differently and I can't find a straightforward answer.

Comment: Yes, appears duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Question should be answered here :

[OSX 10.8 - How to keep a custom dock for all users that login](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100188/osx-10-8-how-to-keep-a-custom-dock-for-all-users-that-login)

Basically, you create your dock in your account, copy the .plist from ~/Library to the System Template Lib and your're done.

Comment: All information I had found on the forums said that this would no longer work. On closer inspection, it was referring to the more aggressive caching and so a reboot was required... so thanks for pointing to this.