# Can dock items be added for multiple OS users?

Tags: macos, dock

Hi can anyone give me a simple step by step procedure for me to be able to use the same dock for two separate users.

I basically have me as two companies and have set up two users to keep everything separate.

But I would like to be able to add icons for  word, photoshop, and illustrator in both user accounts.

Comment: The easiest way probably is to just drag the icons you need into the Dock in both accounts manually. Did you try that?

Comment: See also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100188/osx-10-8-how-to-keep-a-custom-dock-for-all-users-that-login

Comment: @patrix That no longer works on El Capitan due to SIP iirc. Good link nonetheless....

Comment: Copying `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist` from user-1 to user-2 should still work though.

Answer (score 1):

You can script dock additions, but it's actually quite a pain to do correctly and in a general manner.

The time it takes you to read one of the links I will add will be longer than it takes to just log in to each user, add the icons to the dock by hand and then logging out.

- https://github.com/kcrawford/dockutil

The above link is a command line utility to manipulate a user's dock. It also can operate on multiple users at the same time, so I would start with that tool and look for others if this one doesn't work for your needs / abilities.

```
dockutil --add /Applications/Word.app --before 'System Preferences' --allhomes
```