# Hide Siri from default Dock in Sierra

Tags: macos, siri

I would like to create a Dock for all users which does not include Siri. It does not appear in the file `com.apple.dock.plist`, so where is Siri added to the Dock?

Answer (score 2):

I answered a similar question here: [OSX 10.8 - How to keep a custom dock for all users that login](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100188/osx-10-8-how-to-keep-a-custom-dock-for-all-users-that-login/100289#100289)

This answer should still apply to macOS Sierra.

---

Dug up my notes from when I first modified the user template in our base images.  Ran back through the process, changing the default Dock to have about 15 items, on a fresh Mac and these steps worked.  I did a lot of this from the command line, so as to not fuss with changing/reverting permissions using Finder.

1. Arrange your Dock however you would like for it to appear on new user accounts, changing the orientation and adding/removing applications.
2. Browse to **~/Library/Preferences** and copy the **com.apple.Dock.plist** file to your desktop.
3. Open Terminal and start a root session by typing: `sudo -s`
4. Enter your current account's password when prompted
5. Copy the copy of your modified dock preference file from your desktop to the User Template in your Mac's System folder.: `cp ~/Desktop/com.apple.Dock.plist /System/Library/User\ Template/English.lproj/Preferences`

That should do the trick.  I tested this on a fresh Mac by logging into both a Guest account and a new (*created after the above steps*) standard user account, both accounts showed the proper Dock with 15~ items.

It shouldn't be necessary with these steps but if you run into trouble you should verify that the **/System/Library/User Template** folder has permissions set to: *System - Read/Write* & *Everyone - No access*.

Comment: Yes I read it, Siri is still in the dock and file and file them properly

Comment: @Mr Rabbit , You said "_This answer should still apply to macOS Sierra._" and also said "_I tested this on a fresh Mac by logging..._" so my question to you is, did you actually test this under macOS Sierra?

Comment: Does not work under Sierra. Just tried. Apple of course, changed something again, that prohibits how people did their job.