# How to organize Launchpad apps with the command line?

Tags: macos, command-line, launchpad

Is there any way to change the order, create folders, and put apps in folder in macOS Launchpad from command line. I'm trying to automate a macOS clean install, and it's time consuming to reorder manually all the apps.

Comment: This will be interesting. I’m not sure anyone has even documented which file or database contains the Launchpad data [as opposed to the dock data](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100188/) yet here.

Comment: I just found this app: http://launchpadmanager.com. We can export a layout as a file. I guess it would be possible to automate it with AppleScript

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?